# Como seleccionar la id de una option del select de un XML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

Muy Buenas, tengo un archivo XML de provincias y poblaciones de españa(adjunto XML),y lo que quiero hacer es:
2 selects, el primero es para que el usuario elija la provincia y el segundo es para que elija la poblacion acorde a la provincia elejida, yo lo tengo hecho asi, pero no se porque, la variable provincia, que supuestamente recoge la ID de la provincia, me dice que esta undefined. En el succes la primera funcion es la que muestra todas las provincias, ese me lo hace sin problema, el segundo, que comienza en el change, es lo que no me funciona. Si por ejemplo enmed de option:selected introduzco un 1 , si que me funciona, por lo que supongo que el problema proviene de esa variable, que no consigo saber como hacer que detecte el option:selected. Gracias  Adjunto codigo

````
    <head>
        <title>Provincias</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Selecciona la Provincia</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <form action="">
                    <select id="prov" name="provincias">
                        <option value="Selecciona una provincia">Selecciona una provincia</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="localidad" id="localidad" >
                        <option value="Selecciona una localidad">Selecciona una localidad</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
                <script>
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "provinciasypoblaciones.xml",
                        dataType : 'xml',
                        success :  function provincia(xml){
                            var provincias = $(xml).find("provincia");
                            provincias.each(function(){
                                let opt = $('<option>');
                                opt.append($('<option />',{
                                text : $(this).children("nombre").text(),
                                value : $(this).children("nombre").text(),
                                }));
                                opt.append("</option>");
                                $("#prov").append(opt);
                            })
                                                        
                            $("#prov").change(function(){

                                provincias.each(function(){
                                    var provincia = $("option:selected", this).attr("id");
                                    console.log(provincia);
                                    if (provincia == $(this).attr('id')){
                                        $(this).find('localidades').children('localidad').each(function(){
                                            let loc = $('<option>');
                                                loc.append($('<option />',{
                                                text : $(this).text(),
                                                }));
                                                loc.append("</option>");
                                                $("#localidad").append(loc);
                                        })                               
                                    }

     
            
                                })
                            })
                        }

                        });       
           
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html> ```
Adjunto una parte del archivo XML:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lista>
    <provincia id="01">
        <nombre><![CDATA[Alava]]></nombre>
        <localidades>
            <localidad c="0"><![CDATA[Aberasturi]]></localidad>
            <localidad c="0"><![CDATA[Abetxuko]]></localidad>
            <localidad c="0"><![CDATA[Abezia]]></localidad>
        </localidades>
    </provincia>
    </lista>
````

Comment: Prueba esto let localidad = $("#"id del select" option:selected").text();

Comment: No funciona, me sale en vacio